# Display all videos in a folder as a list in HTML 5

Tags: php, html

I have an app where i'm supposed to display all the videos in a single html 5 page, one after the other. I want to use the video tag to do this. I have been able to upload files to my folder but i haven't found a way to display them. I have searched but a lot but i cannot seem to find the right solution. Please help me

Comment: [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get the file names is a good start

Comment: Thanks..let me try that out

Answer (score 2):

You can make it like this:

```
<?php

    $dir = "videos/";
    $videoW = 320;
    $videoH = 240;

    if (is_dir($dir))
    {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)){

            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

                if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){

                    echo 
                    "
                        <div style='display: block'>
                            <video width=\"$videoW\" height=\"$videoH\" controls>
                              <source src=\"". $dir . $file ."\" type=\"video/mp4\">
                              <source src=\"". $dir . $file ."\" type=\"video/ogg\">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                    ";

                }

            }

            closedir($dh);

          }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Awesome..that should work perfectly..thanks a lot Rodrigo. :)